# Pig Latin Program in Python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

Write a program in Python 3 that converts a sentence typed in by the user to Pig Latin. Pig Latin has two rules:

> If a word begins with a consonant all consonants before the first
>   vowel are moved to the end of the word and the letters "ay" are then
>   added to the end. e.g. "coin" becomes "oincay" and "flute" becomes
>   "uteflay". If a word begins with a vowel then "yay" is added to the
>   end. e.g."egg" becomes "eggyay" and "oak" becomes "oakyay".

My code works for individual words but does not work for sentence. I have tried entering:

```
wordList = word.lower().split(" ")
    for word in wordList:
```

but it does not work.

```
#Pig Latin Program
import sys
VOWELS = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')

def pig_latin(word):
    if (word[0] in VOWELS):
       return (word +"yay")
    else:
       for letter in word:
          if letter in VOWELS:
             return (word[word.index(letter):] + word[:word.index(letter)] + "ay")
    return word

word = ""   
while True:
    word = input("Type in the word or Exit to exit:")
    if (word == "exit" or word == "Exit" or word == "EXIT"):
        print("Goodbye")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print(pig_latin(word))
```

The input sentence: `the rain in Spain`

The output sentence: `ethay ainray inyay ainSpay`

Answer (score 0):

So you could do something like this, it returns an iterable of all the pig-ed words and you can join them in the last step. You don't need that last return you have. My guess is the issue you saw was that you are returning in the first loop. you could track the return outside the loop and append to it in the loop and return that also.

```
import sys

VOWELS = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')

def pig_latin(word):
  wordList = word.lower().split(" ")
  for word in wordList:
    if (word[0] in VOWELS):
      yield (word +"yay")
    else:
      for letter in word:
        if letter in VOWELS:
          yield (word[word.index(letter):] + word[:word.index(letter)]+ "ay")
          break

word = ""
while True:
    word = input("Type in the word or Exit to exit:")
    if (word == "exit" or word == "Exit" or word == "EXIT"):
        print("Goodbye")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print(' '.join(pig_latin(word)))
```

Comment: The break is so it only finds the first instance of a vowel

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it. Can you explain the print(’ ’ .join(pig_latin(word)))?

Comment: pig_latin returns an iterable object. Like a list(kinda) the join combines the elements in the iterable with `" "`